# reading a variable into an open file

Tags: fortran90

Hey I am very new to Fortran and Stack overflow .. I wanted to use fortran for an assignment but I am stuck with the run time errors ..
Any help will be greatly appreciated

I am trying to read two variables to a file that I have opened. This is a sample code given to me by my professor but it shows run time error. Please help

```
    subroutine input_data
    implicit none
    real*8 a, b
    open(unit = 5, file = 'inputdata.dat', status = 'unknown')
    read(5,*) a,b
    close(5)
    return 
    end
```

It shows run time error at the read line.

Comment: What error does it produce? What is the content of the file you try to read in? You should specify more details. (Maybe you should also consider to ask your supervisor, why his code does not work...)

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean you want to read variables *from* a file?  Assuming that's what you mean, the code is standard FORTRAN, so the problem must be in the file.  But no one could possibly tell you what the problem is without that error message.  Also, since you are reading text, you can show us the contents of the file, too, since it must be a text file.  One other thing: a unit number of 5 is a little dangerous, since FORTRAN by default considers 5 to be STDIN.  Personally, I never use unit numbers less than 10.

Comment: One more thing, a and b will be lost when you return.  But maybe you're not wanting to worry about that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are reading *from* the file. if so, your status in your open statement is not unknown, but "old". such as:

```
open(unit = 5, file = 'inputdata.dat', status = 'old')
```

the status "unknown" will create the file if it does not exist, and then try to read from it. however, since it was just created, there is nothing in that file, and hence, you get an error.

the status "old" will give you a aruntime error stating that the file does not exist, if the file... does not exist :)